# Unable to execute appium teston real iOS device over wifi (without cable) but same script works fine cable connection

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I want to execute my appium testcases on real iOS device over wifi (without connecting via cable).

I have tried "Connect via network" option in Devices and Simulators. But its just launching the app and closing automatically. Testcase is not executing.Same testcase is executing correctly via cable(if passcode is turn off). 
xCode verison = 10.1
device iOS verison  = 12.4.2

```
@BeforeTest
public void applaunch() throws MalformedURLException {
    dc.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    dc.setCapability("deviceName", "My iPhone");
    dc.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
    dc.setCapability("noReset", true);
    dc.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", "HDYDHGKBDKGJG");
    dc.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
    dc.setCapability("platformVersion", "12.4.2");
    dc.setCapability("useNewWDA", "true");      
    //dc.setCapability("reportDirectory", reportDirectory);
    //dc.setCapability("reportFormat", reportFormat);
    dc.setCapability("testName", testName);
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "Vhduysshs9af42cad204240fdfgfdgdgyjdhdhgdf");
    dc.setCapability("bundleId", "com.estapp.pro.apptest");
    driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);

}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
    driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@name='More']").click();// Click on More button

}

@AfterTest
public void CloseApp() {
    driver.closeApp();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to xcode to enable the wifi "connect via network" checkbox.

[image]

Input this in your terminal

```
idevice_id -l
```

if you see the real device uuid appears , it means you are successful connecting with wifi. You can execute your script from here.

Comment: Yes, Its showing real devices UDID(after disconnecting cable). this UDID is same as using with cable connectivity. But when i clicked on test execution button on eclips it launched the app and closed aumatically. Same happened 4-5 time. Not executing @Test script

Comment: What is the appium log for this ?

Comment: Hi John, Following is my appium log- 
[XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: ""
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"com.urbancompass.prod.external.consumer","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true}}

Comment: I am using appium desktop

Comment: I found 1 clue that this issue is because of device locking. if i turn off the lock then its working fine with cable connectivity.

Comment: For automation , you have to disable to locking